# How to create a PasswordValidator that retrieves validation options from a database or controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am setting up an MVC.NET 4.5 Website with ASP.NET Identity Core 2.2.1.

My goal is to be able to edit Password validation options in the website view and save these validation rules in a DB. I would like the password validator to then use these rules to validate passwords on signup. It should have the ability to use a different set of validation rules for different registration pages during the same run time.

The default implementation of the PasswordValidator is in the identityConfig file. I understand that you can create custom password validators for custom validation rules (i.e using regex expressions to validate).

How can I create a custom PasswordValidator that retrieves validation rules (via either a custom ValidationRulesModel or a regex string) from the DB or has the rules passed in by a controller ?
Is this possible or do I need to look into other solutions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can create a separate class `CustomPasswordValidator` which is inherited from `IIdentityValidator<string>`. You can then implement validation logic in `ValidateAsync(T)` method. There you will retrieve rules from DB and check them against the passed string argument.

Then I suppose you are using a kind of `ApplicationUserManager` class derived from `UserManager`. Add a constructor parameter of `IIdentityValidator<string>` type to `ApplicationUserManager`, assign it to `PasswordValidator` property.

`ApplicationUserManager` instance created with `CustomPasswordValidator` instance as an argument will validate you passwords against DB rules.

See [source](https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/UserManager.cs) of `UserManager` to see when exactly `PasswordValidator` property is called.